# How can i conditionally add any specific React Package at runtime?

Tags: android, react-native

I have a few existing React Packages which are added as library to my current react native app.

Now, one of the packages, needs to be added only if certain condition follows:

**Condition** : If 'isXPackageRequired' is true, then only it should be added as list of react packages.
But this property is in javascript code and should only be read from redux store.

Following is the code where i am adding react packages:

```
public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      List<ReactPackage> reactPackages = Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
              new MainReactPackage(),
              ...,// Some other Packages
             );
     // Here how can i get that redux variable to conditionally include myXPackage
      if(**CONDITION WITH JAVASCRIPT VARIABLE:isXPackageRequired**){
         reactPackageList.add(new MyXPackage());
      }
   }
}
```

OR, is there any other place where i can remove this package if already added and how?

I could have read from buildConfig if it would have been static or environment based, but the ask is at the runtime and if we have the desired property in our redux-store.

I have researched a lot but with no luck. Any elegant solution will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you check the lifecycle of the react-native application ? I am pretty confident that the Redux components are not instantiated yet when you are listing the package your ReactNativeHost must used. So you have two options : find if one can add the package after the application is started (and access redux as usual) or systematically add the package. Why won't you ?

Comment: Thanks @Poutrathor, how can i programmatically add the package other than the way i did? This is exactly what i am looking for.

Comment: Sry, I don't know enough about react-native to answer this question. I would just load the package at start.

Answer (score 0):

The current `reactPackageList` is immutable. You can do a small refactor to change it to a mutable list, but with this next example we loose the autolinking feature.

```
// import of packages here

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      List<ReactPackage> packages = new ArrayList<>();

      packages.add(new MainReactPackage());
      packages.add(new RNDeviceInfo());
      packages.add(new RNBuildConfigPackage(BuildConfig.class));

      // conditionally add package
      if(BuildConfig.MyString.contains("theString")){
        packages.add(new MyNewPackage());
      }

      return packages;
    }

   // rest of class remains untouched
}
```